# Show that if $x, y, \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}∈ \mathbb Q$ then $\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y} ∈ \mathbb Q$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, radicals

> Show that if $x, y, \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}∈ \mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y} ∈ \mathbb Q$.

If $r=\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$, then so is $$r^2 = x + y + 2\sqrt{xy},$$
which implies that $$\sqrt{xy} = \frac{1}{2}(r^2 - x - y) ∈ \mathbb{Q}.$$

From $\sqrt{xy} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$ we have that $\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$. To show this is true we suppose the opposite.

Wlog if $\sqrt{y} \not∈ \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{x} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$, then we would have $\sqrt{xy} \not∈ \mathbb{Q}$.

Assume that $\sqrt{xy} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$ when  $\sqrt{y} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$.

So we have $$\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} = \frac{p}{q}\sqrt{y},$$ where $\dfrac{p}{q} = \sqrt{x}$ and $(p,q)=1$, which is irrational. Contradiction.

I don't know if this is right. Can somebody please help me with this problem and tell me what should I do?

Comment: "From $\sqrt{xy}$ ∈ Q we have that $\sqrt{x}$,$\sqrt{y}$ ∈ Q"   But:  $\sqrt {2\times 2}\in \mathbb Q$ while $\sqrt 2$ is not.

Comment: You say "wlog" in line 4, but you actually forgot to consider the case where $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt y$ are both irrational.

Comment: Did you know that you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs rather than single symbols? For instance, `$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \in \mathbb{Q}$` gives $\sqrt x + \sqrt y \in \Bbb Q$ and looks a bit better than what you have.

Comment: Thank you for that because I'm new to this and I'm sorry if I made any mistakes in writing because English is not my native language

Answer (score 7):

$(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)=x-y$ this implies that $\sqrt x-\sqrt y\in\mathbb{Q}$ as a quotient of two rational.

$2\sqrt x=(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)+(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies that $\sqrt x\in\mathbb{Q}$.